# Style 503 Error Pages Expression Engine

Tags: templates, error-handling, content-management-system, expressionengine

Is there anyway to style the error pages (like the 503 error page attached)? I can find the templates in \system\expressionengine\errors\ but any changes to these will be lost when I update EE.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you log in to your admin section, click on "Design" and then hover over "Message Pages", then click "User Messages". You can insert/edit the CSS that is associated with this page in the head section.

I know this styles the error messages for logging in, submitting forms, etc. and I am assuming it will apply to the same error message you provided. If not let me know.